# With ZMQ I can bind a socket to an endpoint with CLI but not using the same script in Apache2. Why?

Tags: php

Here is the `stream_manager` class:

```
class stream_manager
{

    protected $context;

    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->context = new \ZMQContext();
    }

    public function isPortSuitable(int $portNumber)
    {
        $socket = null;
        try
        {
            $socket = $this->context->getSocket(\ZMQ::SOCKET_REQ);
            $socket->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:' . $portNumber);
        }
        catch(\Exception $e)
        {
            /**  */
        }
        finally
        {
            /**  */
        }
    }
}
```

Regardless of port number I'm getting a `ZMQSocketException: Failed to bind the ZMQ: Address already in use`.

However, if I execute the following script from the CLI I can bind to ports that the `stream_manager` throws out.  I have also used the following script from the web server using `backticks` successfully.

```
try
    {
        $context = new ZMQContext();
        $socket = $context->getSocket(\ZMQ::SOCKET_REQ);
        $socket->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:8080');
    }
    catch(\Exception $e)
    {
        /** */
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            /** */
        }
        catch(\Throwable $e)
        {
            /** */
        }
    }
```

Why won't my instance method bind to any endpoint, when a script executed from CLI (or with `backticks`) will?

Comment: Also ... This is being executed in a Docker container